# I want to hook up a load in parallel to a single phase 220 V start & run cap. motor. Any harm?

Tags: motor

I understand that this may be an "engineering" forum but I think this group may be the the most qualified to answer my question.

After dealing with a cheap mechanical automatic air compressor tank drain I switched to a 120 V "auto drain". Problem is, the air compressor is 208 - 230 V with start & run caps and the "automatic" function of the new 120 V drain, while addressable, runs constantly in its loop unless its unplugged. I want to connect this load  to one of the hot legs of the compressor's motor and the other to neutral so when I turn the compressor on or off, the drain turns on & off. Is there a problem or error with my thinking? Attached, is a schematic showing the 120 V drain labeled as the "new load". Thanks for any help you can provide.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Connecting the 'Auto Drain' unit between one of the hot terminals and neutral (120 V) should pose no problems.

Answer (score 0):

My bad; in the USA 208-230v means **there is no Neutral**. When I opened up the switch to do the deed I saw a black, white & green wire; 2 hots & a ground. I had heard and I confirmed that using the ground as a Neutral is a serious No-No.

Comment: Well, it doesn't always mean that. There *can* be a neutral (often known as "4-wire"). But yeah, if you don't have one where you need it, then you've got a problem :)